# 2 Layers GUI and JDBC, how to connect

Tags: java, user-interface, jdbc

```
    package projectData;

import java.sql.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class projectData {

//Database Globals
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet Result;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      new projectData();

}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public projectData(){
    Connect();
    Selectdata();
    Displaydata();

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public void Connect(){

       try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DB");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM COLLEAGUES";
            ResultSet Result = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );
        }
      catch (SQLException err){

          System.out.println(err.getMessage());

  }

  }



//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void Selectdata(){
        try{
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM COLLEAGUES";
            Result = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
        }
            catch(Exception X){}
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void Displaydata(){


    try{

        Result.next();

        String TF_ID = Result.getString("ID");

        String TF_FIRSTNAME = Result.getString("FIRSTNAME");
        String TF_LASTNAME = Result.getString("LASTNAME");
        String TF_TITLE = Result.getString("TITLE");
        String TF_DEPARTAMENT = Result.getString("DEPARTAMENT");
        String TF_EMAIL = Result.getString("EMAIL");

    }
    catch(Exception x){}



}
}
```

Ok, here is the thing I am trying to create this JDBC structure in two layers, One layer is the actual code where I get all the Data from the tables and have all the SQL Statements. and The other layer is the GUI where I show the stuff.

My question is, if is possible to only display the information in my GUI by running the methods or I have to establish a connection to the database in my GUI.(I am failing to much at trying, I just want to know if I am loosing my time)

Please be gentle I am a total noob in this and I am trying to learn :).

Thanks :D.

Comment: Are you getting an error while trying?

Comment: I think all your errors are being nulled out...  You need to add the line x.printStackTrace() in the catch (Exception x) block of the DisplayData() method.  Same for the SelectData() method.